# All my Internal Data Has Been Removed Without Reset.. Help?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-note-3

When i had charged my Device in morning in Switch-off Mode after Charging i had Boot up the Device (Device Details Below).. I got all my internal data Gone.. All Internal Apps, Apps Data, Music, Video all gone.. I've not did Factory Reset nor Access the Recovery Mode since i've been using the Device..

Device Information :

- **Device Name**     : Samsung Galaxy Note III (SM-N900)
- **Android Version** : v4.4.2 (KitKat)
- **Root**            : Still not Rooted since the Purchase running on Stock OS.

All the Google Apps and Galaxy Plus Apps have been removed out of no-where, even the PlayStore has been Gone.

All the Data is Gone it shows Device Storage have Data but it doesn't appear anywhere nor in File Manager or Computer.

[image: Image (b)]

All the Internal Storage & Downloaded Apps are shown Corrupted.

Internal Storage App data is also Gone.

[image: Image (d)]

**x What's Good :**

Only the SD card Data can be seen and SD card Apps, though the SD card apps
  have been lost its data (such as i have a Chat App which is in SD card it's 
  there but lost its all chat history, when i opened the app it ask to 
  sign-in, and i sign-in and it's all gone all the chats are gone).

**x What i Did :**

- I've tried installing the corrupted apps and then to see in application manager it shows still its an corrupted app.
- I've checked in computer as if it shows, no it shows the new data.
- I've checked whether it shows in Recovery Mode, no it doesn't shows.

Let Me Know For More Information. So Please Help me Out with the Problem and Recover the Data of the Internal Storage.

Comment: I think your eMMC memory is corrupted that's can explain your data loss! I'm afraid that you may not be able to recover your data anymore...

Comment: Same idea as @esQmo_ . You'd better look for your previous backups and send this phone to aftersale repair.

Comment: Is there any solution 'cos i take backup of my documents regularly on weekly basis upon cloud storage and on pc, but i need these week's data, is there any thing i can take out documents from eMMc memory !!